# My bounty got awarded to a wrong answer automatically

Tags: support, bounty

I gave a bounty on this question here:
[Is my argument against Descartes's "I think, therefore I am", logically sound?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/45724/is-my-argument-against-descartess-i-think-therefore-i-am-logically-sound)

The bounty of 75 reputation got awarded to an incorrrect answer automatically.
The answer did not address any of my concerns. The person answering misunderstood my question, and I had rectified my question to make it even simpler, but the answer still has not reflected any of my concerns.

Could you please rectify the problem?
It was also not the highest voted answer, so I am not sure why this has happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [SE-wide FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/205264):

> [Approximately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147576/bounty-not-awarded-after-the-end-of-the-grace-period/147577#147577) 24 hours after the end of the bounty period (once the grace period ends), if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, the bounty may be awarded automatically.
>
> If the author offered the bounty, and accepted an answer that was posted during the bounty period, that answer is awarded the bounty.  Answers created or accepted before the bounty period are not eligible to be awarded the bounty automatically in this manner.
>
> Otherwise, all or half of the bounty is awarded to the highest-scored answer out of those which...
>
> - ...were posted *after* the bounty was started
> - ...have a score of at least +2
> - ...were not written by the bounty starter

We don't have a way to remove a bounty after it has been awarded.

Comment: alright. thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @novice I have not really followed this post, but from what I see it looks like the question has been massively edited; one of the answers also notes that it may not be applicable to the latest version of the question because of this. That is not how SE is designed to work. Posts can be edited for clarification or more information, but it is not the idea to change their meaning. If an answer leads to new questions, it's fine to open a new question about that - please try to avoid starting a sort of discussion by editing the question to answer the points in the answer(s).

Comment: The idea behind that is that this is a Q&A site, not a forum, and that this format helps future readers find the information they need quickly. The page with your question and its answers is hard to get through when you haven't followed it from the beginning, because it has been edited so much and the posts don't stand alone.

Comment: I apologize, but the earlier versions were very hard to understand so I had to edit twice. Forgive me please.

Comment: @novice that's alright, it's not a big deal. Just something to keep in mind. (When unsure how to formulate a question it's also always okay to ask a question about that here on meta.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not know that. I will keep it in mind the next time.

Comment: I also have a long list of ideas I wanted to discuss, but I am not sure how to go about it. Lots of questions, need a lot of answers!